# Add hover function to a class if condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have 2 h3 elements inside a parent div with class 'entry'

```
<div class="entry">
  <h3 class="productsHover">
    <a><img src="image.png" /></a>
  </h3>
  <h3>
    <a>Drillrigs</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Now, when you hover over the image, it has a transition effect defined by the CSS:

```
h3.productsHover img{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
h3.productsHover img:hover{
    left: 6px;
}
```

I do not want to add them into the same parent element(`h3.productsHover`) to which the hover effect is applied. They(the image and the text) should remain in separate `h3` tags

> **QUESTION**: So how do I call the hover effect on the image when in fact hovering over the h3 text element?

Not that I do not want to apply the hover effect over the entire parent element (`.entry`) since it contains many other image and `h3` tags as well.

Also, classes should only be added via JS, and not in the html it self (the normal way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind handler to hover (jQuery supports) event on h3 which has a a text, the handler will add a class on mouseenter and remove a class on mouseout. let css class on h3 which has img to do the effect.

```
$( 'div.entry h3:last-child a' ).hover(
    function(e){ $(this).parent().prev().addClass('productsHover') },

    function(e){ $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('productsHover') }
);
```

Comment: I can't see more source from you, so what i can give is just a clue to code it. Due the fact that the event source and effect is not the same element. so you can: 1. add hover event handler on second h3. 2. define css for effecting on first h3.

Answer (score 1):

@Vimal Stan: this answer should be improved with the following:

```
$(".entry img").prev().addClass("hoverClass"); // of fire hover for that element
// same with this one .entry:hover img
```

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
 .prev( [selector ] )Returns: jQuery

Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
```

Comment: Thank you, but not sure how to implement this. Could you maybe look at the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/77UGU/3/

Comment: I used jquery, but I think you do not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
 .entry img
 .entry:hover img
```

This should let you display the hover effect no matter where the hovers over the div.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the question, i know I can apply the hover the the whole containing parent, but the parent has many images inside it...So all the images will have the effect when I only want one particular image(the one on which I hover) to have the effect...

Comment: You just need to be more specific in the selector to highlight the images you want. [.entry .productsHover img] and [.entry:hover .productsHover img]